# Can this idea work as a number system?

Tags: calculus, integration, number-systems

Each decimal number is equivalent to a function $f(x)$ in this number system. $f(x)$ is defined on the whole number line and only takes single digit integer values 0-9 everywhere. The conversion from function to decimal is given by:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)10^{x}dx$$

Does a unique function $f(x)$ exist in this number system (or maybe 'function system') for each decimal number?

Comment: Did you think about convergence of the integral ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No. What does that mean?

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you're worried about  the integral going to infinity, then that'll never be the case because the $f(x)$ equivalent of every decimal number will be 0 for some sufficiently large $x$ and then 0 at all points after that.

Comment: What function $f$ corresponds to $1$?  Is it the only one?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I've no idea what function corresponds to 1. I tried the function$f(x)=1$ in (0,1) and 0 everywhere else. But that function doesn't correspond to 1. Is finding these functions an unsolvable problem?

Comment: I don't know, this is your question.  But if you're unable to find a unique function that corresponds to a *particular* number, it's unlikely that there's exactly one for *each* number.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I know it seems unlikely. I was looking for some proof about uniqueness from the experts here. My knowledge is very limited.

Comment: The number of functions is uncountable, even on a finite codomain, so uniqueness can't be granted unless you put heavy constraints on the function, that will probably make the system of little use.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What if we drop the '$f(x)$ must be an integer' requirement and restrict $f(x)$  to continuous oscillating sine functions of amplitude 10? I mean, $f(x)$ will be oscillating with amplitude 10 in some intervals and 0 everywhere else. Will the oscillating intervals be unique?

Comment: @RyderRude: no, for the same reasons. There is no fundamental difference between "single digit" and "sinusoid or zero". I think you missed the cardinality argument. Please don't try again with "what about a square root" or "rational values only"... ;-)

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you really want to do.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just thought it'd be a cool idea if every number could be associated with a unique function this way. But that isn't the case.

Comment: @RyderRude: think that there is trivially the function that associates the integer values 0..k to the corresponding digits of the number... and many more

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought my method would give some non trivial functions. The representation of each number in any finite base is unique. I tried to use something like $10^h$ with infinitesimal $h$ as the base but as you pointed out, this representation isn't unique as the continuity of real numbers gives too many degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is not uniquely defined.

For instance, the number $1$ can be represented by

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}0\le x\le \log_{10}(\log(10)+1)\to1\\\text{else }\to0\end{cases}$$

or by

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}0\le x\le \log_{10}\left(\frac{\log(10)}2+1\right)\to2\\\text{else }\to0\end{cases}$$

and in uncountably many other ways.

The continuum of $\mathbb R$ gives you way too many degrees of freedom for the representation to be unique.

Comment: Is it possible to make some restrictions to make this system unique?

Comment: @RyderRude: yes, constrain $f(x)$ to be $1$ in a single interval starting at $0$, and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Graph to show both $f$'s represent $1$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4lx5htw8iv

Answer (score 0):

The Heaviside step function $H(x)$ takes the value $0$ for $x\le 0$ and $1$ for $x>0$. We can use the Heaviside function to construct

$f_a(x)=H(a-x)$

which is $1$ if $x<a$ and $0$ everywhere else. Then we have

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f_a(x)10^xdx=\int^{a}_{-\infty}10^xdx=\frac{1}{\ln 10}10^a$

If $b=\frac{1}{\ln 10}10^a$ then $a(b)=\frac{1}{\ln 10}(\ln \ln 10 + \ln b)$ and

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f_{a(b)}(x)10^xdx=b$

This works for $b>0$ although it is not a very "natural" construction, and I am sure there are many alternatives.

Comment: No, $f$ takes integer values only.

Comment: Good point. I have changed my construction so that $f$ only takes values $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I used the same trick and explicitly showed non uniqueness with $f=2$.